# CKEditor force paste from word?

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

I have a application using the CK editor, where users typically paste content from word.
When the paste from word function is used, then the content is cleaned properly. The problem is with users not using paste from word, then the HTML gets into a state that our application can't clean.

Has anyone found out a way of either forcing using paste from word for word content or automatically apply the logic used when paste from word, even if paste is directly into editor?

I would not like to completely turn off paste into the editor directly, rather I'd like to detect a word paste and then clean the data (as paste from word), or disallowing a paste from word but allowing normal text paste.

I'm using version 3.0.1 CK editor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out that this was included in version 3.1 of CK Editor, then all paste in to normal edit window is passed through the word clean up function.

Comment: right, once you add  c.extraPlugins = "pastefromword" to have it be loaded.

Comment: I think that should be the default behavior. CK editor checks if pasted HTML looks like coming from word, then it cleans it to "normal" HTML

Comment: For anyone looking to force this behaviour on everything (not only text copied from Word). I've posted my solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8379364/407938

Comment: i want to paster as it is any idea paste for word not working