# how to copy data with fontstyle from excel to browser or java?

Tags: java, php, javascript, html, javafx

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [CKEditor - use pastefromword filtering on all pasted content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5227140/ckeditor-use-pastefromword-filtering-on-all-pasted-content)

I am trying to use [`CKEditor`](http://ckeditor.com/).

Adding the following two lines

```
pasteFromWordRemoveFontStyles = false
pasteFromWordRemoveStyles = false
```

to `config.js` make it works fine in `Internet Explorer`, but in `Chrome` coping from word it´s fine and from excel it pastes data without `fontstyle` and `JavaFx (WebView)` word works fine too but from excel it paste data in plain text, how can I fix it?.

what settings do i need to make CKEditor copy the fontslyte from Excel to any browser?

If anyone has another tool with I can copy-paste from MS excel to Java or browser (with fontstyle).

Comment: Are you using the regular paste button or the paste from word button?

Comment: Does it preserve fonts if you use the "Paste From Word" button?

Comment: You might be interested in http://stackoverflow.com/a/8379364/3333 this answer.

Comment: Please rephrase some parts of your question. I don't understand what you are asking.

Comment: from word using ctrl+V and word button it works, but from excel none.

Comment: Hi @PaulTomblin i check that link and try to implement those settings but i obtain the same problem for Chrome and JavaFX and for IE the data lost the backgraound color. those answers were implemented in CKeditor 3.6.2, i'm using CKEditor 3.6.4.